# simplest possible pager

Tags: shell, less, mc, pager

In `mc` (midnight commander), I can define custom command for viewing files, ie:

```
shell/i/.jpg
    Open=gpicview %f 
    View=file %f | less
```

The command `file %f` has to be piped to a pager. I am using here `less` as example.

The problem with less is, it displays the one line in the middle of the screen, and adds these characters:

```
~
~
(END)
```

I just need the simplest, stupidest possible pager that does nothing other than display what it receives from pipe redirection. Something like the `cat` command, which does not add anything to a file that it is displaying.

What can I use instead of `less` ?

Or can I configure `less` to hide those special characters?

## UPDATE:

OK, I have fixed some of the problems in `less` by using the options `--tilde` and `--clear-screen`. However, `less` still shows `(END)` at the bottom of the page.

Can I get rid of the `(END)` ?
If there is no configuration option for that, how could I change it in the sourcecode (I am OK with recompiling less package)

I am using `less` on Debian 10. `less --version` shows:

```
less 487 (GNU regular expressions)
```

Comment: Why do you need a pager and why can't you use cat if it fits your need?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - when I use `View=file %f | cat` in `mc.ext`, it does not work. Nothing happens.

Comment: It probably does work but there's nothing holding the result on screen for long enough for you to see it

Comment: @roaima - yes, exactly. I can see the output when I minimize `mc` with `ctrl+o`. I need some pager to hold the output, and to exit when I press `q`.

Comment: Have you tried `man less`? There are myriad options and it will certainly be possible to remove the `~` placeholders

Comment: @roaima - I found `--tilde` option to hide the `~` characters. But it still displays `(END)`

Comment: Try `less -RXeis`

Comment: Did you give a chance to good old **pg** (deprecated but still included in the util-linux pack)

Comment: @roaima - the `-X` option causes the output to be displayed in the terminal, together with whatever previous output was there. I need just clean screen with whatever output is piped to less. With the `--tilde` option working, I just need to get rid of the `(END)` , and also I would like to have the output start at the top, instead of in the middle of the page.

Comment: file %f | pg -p "";echo -e "\033[1A\033[K"

Comment: `clear; file %f; read` Use {Enter} to quit

Comment: Using `less` with `-E` would stop it from showing `(END)`.  It would terminate instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda - thank you, but that is not what I need, obviously.

Comment: @400theCat "obviously"?

Comment: Sounds like the solution should be in `mc` to tell it the command outputs something (like the needsterminal or copiousoutput settings in mailcap), rather than you having to invoke a pager to view a one line output.

Comment: @400theCat I think that what Kusalananda is getting at is that while you wrote “I just need the simplest, stupidest possible pager that does nothing other than display what it receives from pipe redirection.” it seems that you actually want more than that, you want your pager to also wait for some interaction before exiting, and that’s not explicit in your question.

Comment: I like the tildes and the EOF/END indicators from _pg_ and _less_. Sucks to be you, @400theCat :(

Comment: Would `tail -f -n +1 %f` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mc` has its own internal pager/viewer, no need to invoke a separate one, you just need:

```
type/^JPEG
  View=%view file -- %p
```

(here based on file type (regexp applied to the output of `file`) rather than file name)

See the comments at the top of [the default `mc.ext`](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/misc/mc.ext.in#L1) for documentation.

The default viewer for JPEG files is actually defined as:

```
type/^JPEG
        View=%view{ascii} /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/image.sh view jpeg
        Include=image
[...]
include/image
        Open=/usr/lib/mc/ext.d/image.sh open ALL_FORMATS
        View=%view{ascii} /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/image.sh view ALL_FORMATS
```

Having said that, `less` has:

> `-~` or `--tilde`
> Normally lines after end of file are displayed as a single tilde
> (~).  This option causes lines after end of file to be displayed
> as blank lines.

And the prompt string can be defined with `-Ps'prompt'`. To remove it, including the `(END)` at the end, you can pass `-Ps` alone, though you'll still see a `:`. With `-Ps$'\r'` (or `-Ps"$(printf '\r')"` for shells that don't support the `$'...'` quotes from ksh93), that `:` goes as well.

So:

```
type/^JPEG
  View=file -- %p | less -~ -Ps"$(printf '\r')"
```

If you want something that clears the screen, runs the `file` command with its output untouched and then waits for some key press to exit, you could just do:

```
type/^JPEG
  View=zsh -c 'echoti clear; echoti civis; file -- "$1"; read -sk; echoti cnorm; echoti clear' zsh %p
```

(here also hiding the cursor with `echoti civis` as a bonus).

Instead of staying on the main screen and clearing it upon entry and exit, you could also switch back to the alternate screen (the one normally used by `mc`) as `less` does without `-X` so as to leave the main screen untouched:

```
type/^JPEG
  View=zsh -c 'echoti smcup; echoti home; echoti civis; file -- "$1"; read -sk; echoti cnorm; echoti rmcup' zsh %p
```

(here not bothering clearing it as `mc` will take care of it).

Comment: the `--tilde` option works to remove the `~`, but how do I get rid of the `(END)` at the bottom of the page? (and I know mc has its own internal viewer, but it tries to be too fancy. I need to only display the data, without menus, and headers, and so on)

Comment: `less -E` will cause `less` to terminate when it reaches the end of the file rather than displaying the visual EOF marker `(END)`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, but that would still exit `less` straight away if the output fits in one screen which means the user won't get time to see it. `-Ps` would remove that `(END)`.